# resultSet obtained if parameter containing whitespace concatenated, but not using setString

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have this piece of code, with a prepared statement. I know the query is redundant. the parameter `id` is a string `<space>413530` (" 413530").  Please note the preceding whitespace character.

```
String query = "SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=?";

PreparedStatement newPrepStatement = connection
        .prepareStatement(query);
newPrepStatement.setString(1, id);
resultSet1 = newPrepStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet1.next()) {
    System.out.println("Got a result set.");
    logindata.add(resultSet1.getString("id"));
}
```

I do not get any results after executing this query.

Now, if I use the same statements and append the parameter as part of the string as follows:

```
String query = "SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=" + id;

PreparedStatement newPrepStatement = connection
        .prepareStatement(query);
resultSet1 = newPrepStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet1.next()) {
    System.out.println("Got a result set.");
    logindata.add(resultSet1.getString("id"));
}
```

I get a result as after executing this prepared statement. Same also works with a `java.sql.statement`

I wish to know why the driver ignores the whitespace in the second piece of code, but has a problem in the first part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `setString` the parameter will be bound as a string resulting in this SQL (considering the bound parameter an SQL string):

```
SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=' 0123';
```

If you use concatenation the SQL used will be (considering the concatenated value as an integer, since space will be ignored as part of the SQL syntax):

```
SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=<space>0123;
```

In this case I would advise to convert it to `int` or `long` or whatever it is and bind it with the right type. With `setInt()` or `setLong()`.

And if you field is a string you could normalize it first using for example:

```
String normalizedValue = String.trim(value);
newPrepStatement.setString(1, normalizedValue);
```

or even direct in SQL like:

```
SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=TRIM(?);
```

Comment: but wont `"SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=" + id;` be expanded as `"SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=' 0123';` ? The whitespace still has to count, right?

Comment: no, it'll be "SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode= 0123;"

Comment: and concatenation should be avoided (think on SQL injection)

Comment: @ftom2 So, the driver will trim the whitespace when concatenated?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth I was changing all queries to use prepared statements, when I ran into this problem, for the same reason :)

Comment: The problem is not with the space, the problem is with the '' around the values which indicated to the DB it is a string and then it looks for that exact string including the <space>, but your value is actually an int, so just use setInt(Integer.parsInt(id));

Comment: The column is actually a `varchar` because some ids can be alphanumeric.

Comment: if you have a alphanumeric in the concatenation case it will crash (in case numbers and letters are mixed)

Answer (score 1):

In scenario - 1, the query will look like this

"SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode=' 413530'"

In scenario - 2, the query will look like this

"SELECT RSCode as id FROM Customer WHERE RSCode= 413530"

Comment: Oh, so the space is part of the query, and "appears" as an Integer?